# Force R to include a decimal point in scientific notation

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently using the command:

```
  data.table::fwrite(
    data,
    file.path(
      HOUREMIS_dir, paste0(run_filename, ".HRE")
    ),
    quote = FALSE,
    sep = " ",
    na = "",
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE,
    append = FALSE,
    scipen = getOption(scipen = 2, digits = 10)
  )
```

to save a large data file.  The data will be used in a fortran script that requires the data to contain a decimal point - even in scientific notation.

For example, 0.00000002 should appear as 2.0e-8.  My current method produces 2e-8.

Is it possible to include a minimum number of digits?

Comment: Convert numeric column to string with scientific notation: `format(x, scientific = TRUE)` then fwrite.

Comment: Not sure whether `fwrite` observes this formatting function, but have you given `sprintf('%.1e', your_float_number)` a try?